# What is the relationship between yarn container, spark executor, and nodes available in EMR?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

Say I have a cluster with 1 master node, 3 core nodes, and 5 task nodes. If I run a spark job in YARN cluster mode, the driver would run on the master node (can master node run executor as well?), and I can have X number of executors per container. Do I have 3+5 = 8 containers? Or just 3 containers because only core nodes can store data?

In addition, if I have two spark jobs running concurrently, do I get 2 separate containers per node, 1 for each spark job, or the 2 spark jobs' executors share 1 container per node?

If the number of Yarn containers can be set by user, i.e. total cluter memory / memory per, do the physical number of nodes matter at all?

Comment: You can specify how many executor containers get made manually. The answer also depends on the memory settings given to each process out of how much total. Containers are not shared unless you are caching your datasets between Spark contexts

Comment: Interesting. Is there any relationship between the nodes and containers then? Can I have 1 container shared between two nodes? Does it matter if it's task node or core node?

Comment: The relationship is memory and vcore related. Larger instances can run more containers. All node types are capable of running Spark code, I believe, but tasks run faster on the nodes with the data needed for the task

Answer (score 4):

> If I run a spark job in YARN cluster mode, the driver would run on the
>   master node

Spark driver does not run on the master node. Master node is only for Yarn/resource manager and Spark driver runs on core nodes.

If you run two Spark jobs, both will run on separate containers in a single node or different nodes.

Drivers run on core nodes and task executors usually run on task nodes but you can configure them to run on core/task nodes.